# How to configure module.php if I have two tablse and display data in different views using different controllers

Tags: php, zend-framework

How to configure module.php?
I am trying to fetch data from two tables with in 2 different views using different controllers.
Below is my code that shows you what I am doing in my module, business controller and registration controller.

Module.php

```php
public function getServiceConfig(){
    return array(
        'factories' => array(
            // Instantiating StudentTable class by injecting TableGateway
            'TaskForce\Model\RegistrationTable'=>function($sm){
                $registerationGateway = $sm->get('RegistrationTableGateway');
                $table = new RegistrationTable($registerationGateway);
                return $table;
            },
            //Instantiating TableGateway to inject to StudentTable class
            'RegistrationTableGateway'=>function($sm){
                $dbAdapter = $sm->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
                $resultSetPrototype = new ResultSet();
                $resultSetPrototype->setArrayObjectPrototype(new Registration());
                return new TableGateway('users', $dbAdapter,null,$resultSetPrototype);
            },
            'TaskForce\Model\BusinessTable'=>function($sm){
                $businessGateway = $sm->get('BusinessTableGateway');
                $businesstable = new BusinessTable($businessGateway);
                return $businesstable;
            },
            //Instantiating TableGateway to inject to StudentTable class
            'BusinessTableGateway'=>function($sm){
                $dbAdapter2 = $sm->get('Zend\Db\Adapter\Adapter');
                $resultSetPrototype2 = new ResultSet();
                $resultSetPrototype2->setArrayObjectPrototype(new Business());
                return new TableGateway('business', $dbAdapter2,null,$resultSetPrototype2);
            },
        )
    );
}
```

BusinessController.php

```php
public function indexAction(){
    // Setting layout for this action
    $this->layout("layout/main_layout");
    return new ViewModel(array(
        // Fetching data from database
        'business'=>$this->getBusinessTable()->fetchAll()
    ));
}
```

and RegistrationController.php

```php
public function indexAction(){
    // Setting layout for this action
    $this->layout("layout/main_layout");

    $form = new RegistrationForm();

    $request = $this->getRequest();

    if ($request->isPost()) {

        $registration = new Registration();

        //$form->get('submit')->setAttribute('value', 'Add New User');

        $post = array_merge_recursive(
            $request->getPost()->toArray(),
            $request->getFiles()->toArray()
        );
        $form->setData($post);

        if ($form->isValid()) {

            $registration->exchangeArray($form->getData());

            $this->getRegistrationTable()->saveRegistration($registration);

            // Redirect to list of users

            return $this->redirect()->toRoute('registration');
        }
    }

    return new ViewModel(array(
        'form' => $form
    ));
}
```

Comment: Please be more specific than "please do some help."

Answer (score 0):

If there is a relationship between the Business and the Registration records, you may wish to clarify it. However, if it is simply a matter of code arrangement, you can do this:

BusinessController.php

```
public function indexAction(){
    // Setting layout for this action
    $this->layout("layout/main_layout");
    return new ViewModel(array(
        // Fetching data from database
        'business'=>$this->getBusinessTable()->fetchAll(),
        'registration' => $this->getRegistrationTable()->fetchAll(),
    ));
}
```

RegistrationController.php

```
public function indexAction(){
    // Setting layout for this action
    $this->layout("layout/main_layout");
    return new ViewModel(array(
        // Fetching data from database
        'business'=>$this->getBusinessTable()->fetchAll(),
        'registration' => $this->getRegistrationTable()->fetchAll(),
    ));
}

// rename your index action in registrationcontroller.php to form 
// so that the form is displayed on the formAction
public function formAction(){
    // Setting layout for this action
    $this->layout("layout/main_layout");

    $form = new RegistrationForm();

    $request = $this->getRequest();

    if ($request->isPost()) {
        $registration = new Registration();
        //$form->get('submit')->setAttribute('value', 'Add New User');

        $post = array_merge_recursive(
            $request->getPost()->toArray(),
            $request->getFiles()->toArray()
        );
        $form->setData($post);

        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $registration->exchangeArray($form->getData());
            $this->getRegistrationTable()->saveRegistration($registration);

            // Redirect to list of users
            return $this->redirect()->toRoute('registration');
        }
    }

    return new ViewModel(array(
        'form' => $form
    ));
}
```